# Support AND combinations of tags on the meta filters and RSS feeds

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-filters

The tag filters right now get questions through that have **any** of the tags in the filter. (for example [here's mine](https://stackexchange.com/filters/131546/real-time))

It would be really helpful to support combination of tags where the question goes through only if it has **all** the tags in that combination.

Take for example [generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generics) on SO. It contains every single language that has generics which makes it pretty unusable as a filter. **But** combined with a language tag like [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c#) would be extremely useful ([like you can do on the site itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generics+c%23)).

Comment: +1 I always assumed they were anded, I never looked close enough at my search results to notice I was wrong.